# SQL solution for duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table `DESTI`

```
CODE_DESTI   ENTERPRISE 
-----------------------
1            xx
1            yy
12           pp
12           oo
12           ll
```

How can I update the duplicate `CODE_DESTI` with auto increment 1 number after it

```
CODE_DESTI   ENTERPRISE 
-----------------------
11            xx
12            yy
121           pp
122           oo
123           ll
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How do you know that appending the number won't clash with an existing record? (In fact in your example it would except for the fact that `12` needs to be de-duplicated)

Comment: I'm not clear about your usage scenario. You have the five records in the DESTI table, and when you try to insert a duplicate row, you want a row inserted with a different CODE_DESTI value?

Comment: yes because  CODE_DESTI must be a unique value

Comment: So why not just drop `CODE_DESTI` and add an `IDENTITY` column to the table? What does this renumbering scheme get you?

Comment: i see your idea, i can not do that because my client presist their CODE_DESTI

Comment: @user609511 And if your client isn't using specific values, you can drop your old `CODE_DESTI` column and rename your new identity column to that, right?

Comment: my client have made a mistake, some of their CODE_DEST is good, but some of them are duplicate. so my idea is to add 1 number auto increment behinde the duplicate one

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a Window function:

```
SELECT
    CODE_DESTI + CAST(RANK() AS varchar) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE_DESTI ORDER BY ENTERPRISE) AS CODE_DESTI,
    ENTERPRISE
FROM DESTI
```

Comment: `||` is standard SQL, but is not supported by MS SQL Server, which uses `+` for string concatenation (and for that reason will also require a cast to a string type).

Comment: @hvd: Thank you. didn't know that, I thought `||` was also supported. Either way I've changed it but since I don't have a table definition I will leave the string cast out. It might already be a string ;)

Comment: I'm fairly certain the result of `RANK()` won't be :)

Comment: @hvd: doh... completely forgot about that :P You are completely right of course.